# Where to find icons of common Windows applications?

Tags: windows, icons

I'm building an **webapp** that helps people to track their desktop application usage. I'd like to show most common Windows applications (like Excel, SolidWorks, AutoCAD, Photoshop, Eclipse, Visual Studio, Winamp, VLC etc.) with their **icon**. Is there any single great collection of application icons out there or should I collect and package those icons myself?

Comment: Note that even when you find these icons, you may not have the right to use them.  (I am not a lawyer.)

Comment: You might have a point here. Just looked at the trademark guidelines from Adobe: http://www.adobe.com/misc/linking.html

Answer (score 1):

They're actually stored *within* the executable (or DLL or some other file) and you can extract them with a tool like [IconsExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iconsext.html) (I have no affiliation with the developers of this software but I've used it in the past).

You *may* find yourself in a precarious legal situation (depending on your jurisdiction) if you try to collect all the icons yourself. They're almost certainly covered under copyright and I'm not sure this is a valid "fair use" scenario. But I'm not a lawyer and I'm certainly not *your* lawyer, so take that with a grain of salt :-)